# Linux not mounting a split partition with dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Error keep on getting when I try to mount my Windows 10 hard drive to get documents off it.

Here is the error code:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/linux/7C2A2F6F2A2F259C: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda2" "/media/linux/7C2A2F6F2A2F259C"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: Restart it once and then try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: @Rahul I tryed but it did not work

Comment: Try `sudo update-grub`. This might help

Comment: @Rahul When i am done must i restart my pc?

Comment: @AidanTaylor Yes, You need to restart.

Comment: It did not work. I am just going to try something with the disk

Comment: I know what the partiton might be doing I had mounted it the ejected it how would I fix that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the fast startup setting in Windows 10. It's enabled by default and is a hybrid shutdown.

Control panel - power options - choose what the power buttons do.
Uncheck the "Turn on fast startup".

Now shutdown Windows 10 and boot Linux again.

Comment: I can boot into linux but I can boot into Windows

Comment: @AidanTaylor You probably meant to say "I **can't** boot into Windows". If that's the case your options are severely limited. And Ubuntu is NOT a tool to fix Windows but you can try some methods outlined in the duplicate answer (the one you didn't bother reading) for retrieving data from that partition. What you can recover at this stage depends on the partition status: If just hibernated as mentioned in this answer then mounting it read only should allow access to the data. If, however, it has logical and/or physical errors, it may not be possible to recover data from there.